# how to iterate front and back in php foreach array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to achieve this

```
foreach($spacecount as $x => $x_value)  {                                                               
    if($spacecount[$x+1] < $spacecount[$x+2] )  {                                                                    
        echo $spacecount[$x];                                                               
    }
}
```

like we can do it in for loop, but i also want to use its key when needed. how can I perform it ?

The array looks like

```
Array (     [ Tables] => 5 
            [Home] => 0 
            [ Wallet] => 5 
            [Designer] => 0 
    )
```

it contains whitespaces in the key text

Comment: What does your array look like that you are processing

Comment: Array ( [     Tables] => 5 [Home] => 0 [     Wallet] => 5 [Designer] => 0 ) . it counts whitespaces in the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's no guarantee that your array is numerically indexed, you can do this:

```
$keys = array_keys($spacecount);
$values = array_values($spacecount);
for ($i = 0;$i < count($spacecount)-2;$i++) {
    //If you need the key you can use $keys[$i]
    if ($values[$i+1] < $values[$i+2]) {
        echo $values[$i+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all this time i was searching for how to iterate back and forth.